# Subscript and equal to sign in Barplot function in R

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I'm trying to write a<sub>b</sub> = 0, and use this as one of the labels for a column on the x-axis of my barplot (using default R Barplot). However, I am unable to use a subscript along with the equal to sign as the subscript seems to require "expression()" while the equal to sign requires quotation marks.

I have tried:

```
barplot(plot1[c(2,4), ], beside = TRUE, names.arg = colnames(expression(a[b] =0, "Hello"))
```

and

```
barplot(plot1[c(2,4), ], beside = TRUE, names.arg = colnames(c("a[b] =0", "Hello"))
```

but neither fit my purposes.

New to R so any help is appreciated!

Comment: why are you trying to use `colnames`? `barplot(1:2, beside = TRUE, names.arg = expression(a[b] ==0, "Hello"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `==` in the expression, and using `colnames()` is not correct. See [Axis labels in R plots using expression() command](https://www.dataanalytics.org.uk/axis-labels-in-r-plots-using-expression/).

Example:

```
barplot(GNP ~ Year, 
        data = longley, 
        beside = TRUE, 
        names.arg = c(LETTERS[1:15], expression(a[b] == 0)))
```

Result:

[image]